# What is the maximum count of Webhook subscrption for Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking at the [Create Subscription API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation.

I would like to understand how many subscribers can I register for an app. Our system has 2000+ users and we are looking to set up a webhook subscription per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

> **Maximum subscription quotas:**
>   Per app: 50,000 total subscriptions 
>   Per tenant: 35 total subscriptions across all apps 
>   Per app and tenant combination: 7 total subscriptions

Comment: Clarification: Those limits only apply to subscriptions for resources in Azure AD: users, groups. They do not apply to resources in Exchange (messages, events).

Answer (score 1):

The limits depend on the type of resources you are subscribing to.

For example, if you are subscribing to `/users` or `/groups`, then there are limits [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks).
Note that you would likely need a single subscription per tenant to track changes to all users/groups.

If you are subscribing to `/messages`, then you can create a subscription for each user mailbox.